# Data binding not working in an event in directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I cannot get the data binding to work in this directive. The variables are not bound properly when I change them inside the event handler,

What am I doing wrong? > [Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHRxA/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('inputTest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="input-group">\
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />\
                    <br>child scope: {{myValue}}\
                  </div>',
        scope: {
            myValue: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).on('click', function (e) {
                alert('c');
                scope.myValue = 'clicked';
            });
            scope.myValue = 'not clicked';
        },
    };
})

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myValue = 'parent value';
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">parent scope: {{myValue}}
    <input-test my-value="myValue"></input-test>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser console?

Comment: No, check the fiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not forget to call `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the event handler.
2. First level bindings may not work as expected due to how prototypical inheritance works. If you try the first point and still get no results, try putting `myValue` a level deeper:

   ```
   $scope.data.myValue = 'parent value';
   ```

   and:

   ```
   <input-test my-value="data.myValue"></input-test>
   ```

Comment: Thx, the line `scope.myValue = 'not clicked';` actually works, only the one in the event handler doesn't.

Comment: Did you actually put the `$apply()` call in the event handler? Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qHRxA/1/

Comment: No I didn't lol. But don't understand why it works outside of the event handler but not inside...

Comment: `$apply()` tells Angular to re-evaluate the watched expressions and take action if any of them changed. Angular's events (e.g. `ng-click`) call `$apply()` under the hoods. Events "external" to Angular have to do it manually.